# How to configure Octopress to support Pandoc fenced code blocks the same as back tick code blocks?

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll, octopress, pandoc

**How do I configure Octopress to format Pandoc-style fenced code blocks in the same way that Backtick Code Blocks are supported?**

I've configured Octopress to use Pandoc as the Markdown parser for my posts.

plugins/pandoc.rb:

```
require 'open3'
module Jekyll
# Just return html5
class MarkdownConverter
def convert(content)
    flags  = @config['pandoc']['flags']
    output = ''
    Open3::popen3("pandoc -t html5 #{flags}") do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
        stdin.puts content
        stdin.close
        output = stdout.read.strip
    end
    output
    end
end
end
```

_config.yml:

```
markdown: pandoc 
pandoc:
    skip: false
    flags: '--smart --mathjax --highlight-style=pygments'
```

Octopress generates really nice highlighting to code blocks like this:

````
``` [language] [title] [url] [link text] [linenos:false] [start:#] [mark:#,#-#]
code snippet
```
````

However, Pandoc fenced code blocks are not being rendered properly by Octopress (no syntax highlighting, etc).  For example:

```
~~~ {.bash}
echo hi
~~~
```

Anybody found a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/octopress/xCgiDkHLtQ8

Brandon Mathis recommmended:

> You could build your own plugin which uses a Pandoc compatible regex, but Pandoc is not supported by Octopress by default.